# the definition of order relation in Munkres's Topology

Tags: logic

In Munkres book, he defines an order relation as follows:
A relation $C$ on a set is called an *order relation* if it has the following properties:

1.(comparability) for every $x$ and $y$ in $A$ for which  $x\neq y$, either $xCy$ or $yCx$.

2.(nonreflexivity) for no $x$ in $A$ does the relation $xCx$ hold.

3.(transitivity) If $xCy$ and $yCz$, then $xCz$.

what is the formal definition of $x "=" y$ here, since it is not really very clear how to understand what he mean by $x \neq y$ here.

Comment: Why is '=' a confusing symbol? In what logic would '=' not be defined?

Comment: $x = y$ means $x$ and $y$ denote the same element in the set the relation is defined on.

Comment: Think about the trichotomy of real numbers. If $x\neq y$ then $x<y$ or $y<x$. Here "$<$" is the "C".

Comment: As Bishop would say: "No entity without identity". It's assumed in mathematics that we always know when two things of some sort are equal if we're claiming to understand the sort.

Comment: Equality itself is a relation.

Comment: Basically, for number 1, he's saying that either $x=y$, $x{\rm\;C}\;y$, or $y\rm{\;C}\;x$. An example of this type of relation is $<$, the less-than relation, on the set real numbers.

Comment: @Akiva: The question has nothing to do with topology or orders, it's about the definition of equality.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of equality between two elements of a set is implicit in the axioms of ZFC set theory.

Elements of sets are again sets (under the hood) and so equality of elements is just the equality of those two sets. The [axiom of extensionality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) is what tells you when two sets are equal.